# Incluir e remover elementos de um Json com a lib Gson (Java)

Tags: java, json, gson

Estou utilizando a biblioteca Gson em Java, tenho a seguinte estrutura em um arquivo json:

```
{"idAluno":4, "nomeAluno":"Teste da Silva", "listaDeTurmas":[1,2,4]}
```

É possível, com essa biblioteca, alterar a entrada "listaDeTurmas" para incluir/remover valores dela?? Por exemplo, adicionar o valor 3 ou remover o valor 4. 
Ou então, existe alguma outra biblioteca de manipulação de Json que me forneça uma função para isso?

Comment: Lembrando que a ideia é não precisar deserializar o registro, alterá-lo e depois inserir no arquivo json de volta. Pois o arquivo tem vários registros como esse, e seria necessário reescrevê-lo inteiro colocando o registro em questão modificado, uma vez que não é possível alterar somente uma linha do arquivo (ou é?). Me parece mto esforço para uma operação relativamente simples e que vai ser realizada diversas vezes.

Comment: Você pode converter o json para uma classe do java com o gson e manipular ela normalmente e, se necessário, transformar em json de novo com o gson

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, mas após transformar o registro alterado em json de novo, para colocá-lo de volta no arquivo vou ter q reescrever todo o arquivo (todos os outros registros). Seria semelhante a uma operação de exclusão em arquivo texto. Não dá pra editar só uma linha. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: Basicamente você lê um arquivo .json altera um array dentro dele e retorna o novo arquivo .json, isso?

Comment: Isso. Cada linha do arquivo tem um registro como oq postei de exemplo. Dentro de uma linha específica, quero alterar somente os valores da id listaDeTurmas, adicionando ou incluindo valores.

Comment: [Aqui](http://respostas.guj.com.br/44724-como-ler-e-alterar-linhas-especificas-de-arquivotxt-atraves-do-java) tem uma pergunta no guj que pode te ajudar (sem gson)

Comment: Dê uma olhada na biblioteca json.org, ela deve te atender.